# java 3d no j3dcore-d3d in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I a using eclipse and JAVA3D 1.5.1 x64,
I added the libary to eclipse and put C:/Program Files/Java/Java3D/1.5.1/bin as Native Libary Location.
 when I'm trying to run Hello3d It's says no j3dcore-d3d in java.library.path.
I have j3dcore-ogl.dll in the bin folder but not j3dcore-d3d.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Java3D 1.5.1 is no longer maintained, it uses Direct3D under Windows 64-bit by default but it can be changed by using the property j3d.rend. However, this version contains numerous unfixed bugs. Please switch to Java3D 1.6.0, this version is more stable and easier to use as there is no native library to setup: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D